# Error: msum(X, window, [minPeriods]). Window must be at least 2. What is the reason?

Tags: dolphindb

I have tried using msum with variable window according to the function as under but it always gives me an error "window must be at least 2". Can anyone help me solve this?

This is my stream table. share `` streamTable(1:0, `ts`symbol`price`vol`time,[TIMESTAMP, SYMBOL, DOUBLE, DOUBLE, TIMESTAMP]) as ip1 ``.

And, this is my normal table
`t3 = select *, mod(minute(ts), 5)+2 as v1 from ip1`

The followings give an error
 `select *, mod(minute(ts), 5), msum(vol, int(mod(minute(ts), 5)+2)) from ip1`
 `select mod(minute(ts), 5), msum(vol, int(mod(minute(ts),5)+2)) from ip1`

And these also give error...
`select *, msum(vol, int(v1)) from t3`
`select msum(vol, int(v1)) from t3`

Answer (score 0):

`msum` is an aggregate function, and it cannot be used with '*'.

If the window size is fixed, you could just type it in the function. Looks like you want to do window calculation on timestamp column. DolphinDB provides function `tmsum` with which you can calculate sum in windows defined by ts duration. For example `tmsum(ts, vol, 2s)`.